# ORACLE - Remove line breaks from a text field

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I extract the txt field from database, it's bringing the text with the line breaks and it's misconfiguring when I export to excel

There is a way to leave all the text on one line and not bring these line breaks

Example?

Currently:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

how i would like, eveything in 1 line

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REPLACE`:

```
SQL> select text from test;

TEXT
---------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet,
consectetur


SQL> select replace(text, chr(10), '') new_text
  2  from test;

NEW_TEXT
---------------------------------------
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet,consectetur

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TRANSLATE` function.

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(txt_field, 'x'||CHR(10)||CHR(13), 'x')
FROM yourtable
```